# Has kubuntu 20 functionality "Freeze Task manager"?

Tags: kde

New kubuntu 20 seems has no functionality "Freeze Task manager".
Just exclude acassional removing of menu items  in Task manager.
But prior kubuntu had such functionality.

Can I add such functionality in kubuntu 20 ?

```
$ uname -a
Linux master-laptop 5.11.0-37-generic #41~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 24 09:06:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
5.11.0-37-generic
x86_64
$ plasmashell -v
plasmashell 5.18.5

$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.12.8
KDE Frameworks: 5.68.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Details matter, so please be exact. Ubuntu has both releases that are *snap* only which use the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20) and *deb* packages that use *year.month* format (eg. Kubuntu 20.04 LTS). There is no *snap* only Kubuntu - it's a desktop which is *deb* based & thus 20.04 or 20.10. The 20 represents 2020, so it's not new (21.10 is the newest, ie. 2021-October release), so what are you asking about?

Comment: I added info about my system

Comment: The details you added match a 20.04 LTS system and not a 20 system (*in fact if you look it says 20.04 using the HWE kernel stack*!). There is no *snapped* version of KDE so are you using 20.04 and not 20?   20 != 20.04